# Django: using standard Auth lib in my models

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to use standart django User library in my models with ForeignKey? I tried to use this code:

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    uploader = models.ForeignKey('django.contrib.auth.models.User')
```

But it throws an error such as this User model doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uploader = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```